# Example for COMPILE_DEFINITIONS vs. INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS

Tags: cmake

I am reading the cmake docs and fail to understand the difference between the two. To me it all boils down to "-Dsomedef" passed to e.g. GCC, but when should one use the one and not the other? I'm using C++.

Edit: For a practical task, right now I have a OS-level run-time test that checks behavior of function that returns path and name of the running process (of itself). For this test I have to pass the reference value of the path and name defined at compile time. target_compile_definitions can do this, but it requires to select between INTERFACE/PUBLIC/PRIVATE.

Edit2: The cmake reference only mentions "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS" and "INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS" when explaining INTERFACE/PUBLIC/PRIVATE:
 https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html

Comment: What is the context for your question? I.e. How are you using these properties in your CMake code? Are you setting them for specific targets, or on directories..? Please provide a more concrete example, if possible.

Comment: Edited the original post.